# Split big apps in django

Tags: django, django-models

I've an app which is growing pretty big, doing too much thing as a single app, so I'd like to split it in 2 or 3 "sub-apps"

The problem is that there are a dozen of models which are linked to each other (foreing key, manytomanyfields, etc.)

I've read LOTS of times that apps should be self-consistent, so, are there any best practices to split a big app in several ones linked to each other?

--> how bad is importing models from other apps?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't hear about a best practice solution, but here's what I would usually do, and I split apps a lot:

#### Step 0 - When is an app "too big"?:

An app should be an (independent) logical unit. Independent is actually misleading, of course you can have dependencies like `django.conrib.auth`, what you should have tho are cross dependencies. They will eventually lead to looping imports. That being said, you app can grow quite large, with is totally fine.
If you having problems organizing your code, I may remind you of the fact that every module can be build as a package. You simply split your `models.py` into `models/__init__.py` and `models/LOGICAL_UNITS.py`.

The only reason why you should split an app is because you can, not because you want to ;)

#### Step 1 - Overview

Use [django_extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html)' graph printing capabilities.

This should give you a good overview an might help you to find so called "communities". Groups of models that have strong cross dependencies.
Those communities usually make a pretty good app.

#### Step 2 - Naming:

If you cant find a name for you're new application, it probably isn't one.